# Truncate and reload

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, gremlin, bulk-load, amazon-neptune

I'm trying to truncate the Neptune db and reload same data by bulk-load
but the database is not considering the same data to load in to Neptune.
we used g.V().drop() and similar for edges. can any one help me with this problem. my project involves schedule based truncate and reload the data with modifications and will have same Id's

we delete the instance and recreate Neptune Again then the load work's fine

```
curl -X POST \
    -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
    https://*:8182/loader -d '
    {
      "source" : "s3://***",
      "format" : "csv",
      "iamRoleArn" : "",
      "region" : "*",
      "failOnError" : "FALSE",
      "parallelism" : "MEDIUM"
    }'
```

number of records provided and the number Neptune bulk-loader identified are not matching and reload fails for same data which got success for the first Time

Comment: Hi Pradeep, do you need more info here? Else, do you mind accepting the answer so that we can close this one out?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that your drop request completed fully? Depending on your data scale, truncating the whole db can take a bit of time and IO, and in almost all cases, its a better option to just create a new cluster and use that instead for such use cases. There are use cases where customers create empty clusters (with no instances in them) and make their application claim on of the empty clusters, add an instance to it, and start using it if they want a clean slate database.

#### Things to note

1. Dropping a big database can take time
2. Dropping the DB involves a lot of IO, and it incurs charges
3. Deleting a cluster and using a new one is often faster, and its cheaper as well
4. You can have empty clusters lying around which cost close to nothing, and you can provision an instance just when you need to
5. Adding an instance to an existing cluster or creation of a new cluster usually takes less than 10mins, and you can always build login in your app to plan ahead and provision the new DB, switch your application and then terminate your old cluster (with or without a final snapshot).